# Call the rest of the javascript after an Ajax event

Tags: javascript, ajax

Hi

I am trying to do an auto complete functionality for an input field.
*psuedo code*

```
<input type="text"/>

<script>
 var ref,resp;//Global Variables

$('input').live('keyup',function(){
   /* Get the input offset, so that list container can be palced at the bottom of the input once get the values through Ajax call */

  ajaxCall();

 /***
  Here I want to write a code to create a div and place the values with in the div and show at the respective input field.
 ***/

});

function ajaxCall(){
var ref  = new XMLHttpRequest();
  ref.open();
  ref.readStateChange = function(){
    if(ref.readyState == 4 && ref.status ==200)
       resp = ref.responseText();
  }
  ref.send();
}

</script>
```

The problem that I am getting here is, the part of the code that is after ajax call should be executed once ajax readyState is 4 and values are retrived.

But that code is being executed when readyState is 1(Its not being called after the other states) where the values are not retrieved from the database.The lets me unable to show the list.

***Note***: I know that the below part can be put in ajaxCall but it contains  some variables which can be set at the place....

Does my problem make sense? If so,can some body let me know the solution...

Comment: jQuery has a great abstraction layer over XmlHttpRequest, namely the `$.ajax` function

Comment: @Alnitak Yeah..But as I mentioned ,some of the code which has to be executed after ajax call has some variables and data which can be set at the previous function only.....

Comment: Also not sure what version of jQuery you are using but `.live()` has been deprecated since 1.4

Comment: @RamaRaoM that's not a problem, you just need to make sure those variables are in scope.  You just can't _call_ the code that needs those variables until after the AJAX has finished.

Answer (score 1):

You have to call the functions that depend on the result of the AJAX call during the AJAX callback. That's just how it is:

```
function ajaxCall(callback) {
    var ref = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ref.open();
    ref.readStateChange = function() {
        if (ref.readyState === 4 && ref.status === 200) {
             resp = ref.responseText();
             callback.call(null, ref.responseText); // invoke the callback here
        }
    }
    ref.send();
}
```

and then:

```
ajaxCall(function(resp) {
    // handle "resp" here
});
```

That said, please don't re-invent the wheel.  You'll end up with code that's hard to maintain and not portable across browsers.  There's plenty of libraries that make AJAX code like this a complete doddle.  I use jQuery.

Comment: I am already passing two variables to this function.So I want pass this cb , is this should be as first param / last param?

Comment: @RamaRaoM it can be whichever one you want.  It doesn't matter so long as you're consistent.

Answer (score 0):

The code that you expect to run after the completion of ajax call should be put in the onSuccess() or onComplete() method of your code.

```
ajaxCall(function(resp) {


    /***
      Here I want to write a code to create a div and place the values with in the div and show at the respective input field.
     ***/
});
```

i.e.. This part of your code must come in the onComplete() method, whic will have the data returned by the ajax call as parameter.